# Que signifie l'expression « être au vilain » ?

Tags: sens, expressions

Bonjour,

Pourriez-vous m'aider à comprendre ce passage dans *Guignol's Band* avec l'expression ***être au vilain ?***

L'expression apparaît dans le contexte du dénigrement de tous ceux qui ne parlent que de la guerre, posent aux experts militaires, se comportent comme s’ils avaient « bouffé du canon ».

«'Barrez Tourlourous! Un sou les douze balles! Allez youp!' Les voilà qui volent! Ils se connaissent plus d'***être au vilain***!...»

Peut-on supposer qu'il y a une référence à l'expression *il va y avoir du vilain ?* ou y-a-t-il une troncation de l'expression *être dans de vilains draps ?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C'est un mot d'argot pour *front, zone de combat*<sup>1</sup>.

Le sens est donc quelque chose comme:

> ils (ne) se connaissent plus d'avoir été au front ensemble !

Le texte parle d'anciens soldats qui, un an auparavant, seraient repartis avec entrain au combat mais qui aujourd'hui se dégonfleraient.

> *Barrez Tourlourous*: Au combat soldats !
> [...]
> *Les voilà qui volent* : Ils s'échappent, disparaissent
> *Ils se connaissent plus d'être **au vilain*** : Confrontés au combat, **au front**, ils ne se connaissent plus eux-mêmes. Ils sont méconnaissables, ils désertent.

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Source: *Romans*, Volume 3, p 1214, Louis-Ferdinand Céline, Henri Godard, Gallimard, 1988.</sub>

Comment: Merci pour votre réponse. Pensez-vous que cette note de l'éditeur a du sens ? Je ne suis pas complètement persuadé. J'ai vérifié la traduction anglaise de ce même passage et on trouve : "Get going, soldier boy! Bullets a penny a dozen! Up and at'em'! Off the fly! They're all raving bughouse!" (CÉLINE, 1954, p. 49). Peut-on trouver cette comprehénsion de "être au vilain" comme "front, première ligne" dans d'autres sources ?

Comment: Je n'ai pas trouvé d'autre source pour l'expression, mais ça me semble plausible.  On leur donne des munitions, ils décollent, sont tout de suite dans l'action, se tirent les uns sur les autres...

Comment: Merci beaucoup !

Comment: @Ovide Pour être franc, je n'avais pas vraiment lu le paragraphe qui précédait cette citation dans le roman. Je dois modifier ma dernière interprétation parce qu'elle ne colle pas avec le contexte. Le sens du mot *vilain* n'est cependant pas affecté.

Comment: Voilà ! Mille mercis ! Je suis plus persuadé maintenant !

Answer (score 0):

Dans le contexte du livre, il me semble qu'un commandant est en train d'encourager ses soldats, en leur disant :

> - les balles ne sont pas chères, donc, continuez à tirer, il y en a plein; l'ennemi fuit et nous gagnons parce que l'ennemi ne connait plus être vilain/courageux.*

*They're all a raving bughouse* veut dire *« ils deviennent fous »* c'est-à-dire, incapable d'être aussi courageux qu'avant: *They're not the bad-asses they thought they were a moment ago.*

Comment: I don't understand how the first bit isn't: They no longer know each other....Could you explain that to me??